# IOs/phonegap - can't submit to itune - Invalid Segment Alignment

Tags: ios, cordova

I get the following error after submitting the app to itune:

```
Invalid Segment Alignment - The app binary at 'Envisearch.app/empty.o' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version.
```

Our model is that we sell the same app as a white label to other companies.

I've being uploading the code with no such issue many times before.

What does it mean? how can I over come it?

Upgrade of Xcode didn't help

I tired to upload an app that was already uploaded and approved, but I get this same error - which I didn't get on previous upload.

So it's a new Apple/itune bug - thank u apple for the grate job.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, browse your files. Under Resources, remove reference to empty.cpp.

This file has the following content:

```
// an empty file to have the compiler include C++ standard libraries.
```

Which causes the error.

I believe it's an unnecessary cordova file.